# JavaScript (Next.js) won't preload images without console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I'm trying to create a scroll-based animation functionality similar to this project.
https://codepen.io/j-v-w/pen/ZEbGzyv

But the thing is, when I define and execute this snippet inside useEffect, this will cause the images to flick, meaning they are not preloaded

```
const preloadImages = () => {
      for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = currentFrame(i);
   }
 };

 preloadImages();
```

But if I add console.log(img), it will load images and work fine.

```
const preloadImages = () => {
      for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = currentFrame(I);
        console.log(img)
   }
 };

 preloadImages();
```

Is there any way to load the images without logging it?

this is my whole code for refrenece
https://replit.com/@farhadham/GiantTepidGraduate#src/App.jsx

Comment: Can you check the network tab if the request is being made? Here is a minimalistic example and looks like preloading does work: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-burnell-nbr5qz?file=/src/App.js Check the network tab

Comment: @vighnesh153 I checked the network and both with or without console.log, the images get loaded with a status of 304.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the image in the onLoad of image in `updateImage` function? `const updateImage = (index: any) => { img.src = currentFrame(index); img.onload = () => context.drawImage(img, 0, 0); };`

Comment: @vighnesh153 tried that, but still not working. I just think I have to somehow use the img inside the loop. For example if there was a way to console.log(img) without showing it.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to debug without complete reproducible example. Can you add minimal code to the replit so that we can reproduce that and on the portal and help with the issue? Please replicate the issue on replit.

Comment: Found a solution for it. instead of logging it to console. I just defined an empty array and pushed each image to it, so I've used them actually @vighnesh153